# DataNucleus object lookup throws sometimes

Tags: java, mysql, persistence, datanucleus

I am using DataNucleus to persist a ProtoBuf message in MySQL database. When I receive a message I try to store it in my database, however the message might already exist in the database, in this case I update the corresponding row with the new data. Here is the logic I use to detemine whether the message exists in my database:

```
PersistenceManagerFactory factory = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("Foo");
PersistenceManager manager = factory.getPersistenceManager();
Transaction tx = manager.currentTransaction();
tx.begin();
MyClass result = manager.getObjectById(MyClass.class, pk /*a string which is the primary key*/);
if(result == null) //message does not exist
else //message exists!
//..more stuff
tx.commit();
```

The `getObjectById` method returns null in case of the row does not exist. Based on that I decide whether I want to update the row (if it exists) or add a new row (if it does not exist).
Suddenly `getObjectById` started throwing an exception, here is the stack trace:

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusObjectNotFoundException: No such database row
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.request.FetchRequest.execute(FetchRequest.java:359)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.fetchObject(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:319)
        at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.loadFieldsFromDatastore(AbstractStateManager.java:1147)
        at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.validate(StateManagerImpl.java:4294)
        at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.findObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3553)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1723)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1741)
```

Which is very strange to me since I didn't modify my code. However I started using two instances of my program connected at the same time to MySQL database.

Is it possible that I did something wrong here or is it a concurrency problem with DataNucleus?

Comment: and the SQL invoked is ? What is in the database? where is the persistable class?

Comment: The table contains a string (PK) and an integer. The database has only this table. No SQL invocation, if I get the object I just mutate it, the new state of the object is persisted in the database. All of this is done inside the transaction.

Comment: How can there be no SQL invocation? You say getObjectById and it will send SQL to FIND the object; where else do you think it finds the object? See the Log

Comment: I am working on object model level and "should" not care about the query engine layer underneath which is the whole idea of DataNucleus I guess. I am not "directly" invoking SQL statements. My question is why did DataNucleus throws an exception sometimes. Did I do something wrong? is there another deterministic way to find out whether an object (=database row) exist or not in DataNucleus API?

Comment: How can anyone answer your question without any DEBUG ? This is HOW you find out what the problem is. Look at the SQL invoked, and look at the data in your DB and likely your answer is there. The log also tells you WHEN an SQL statement is invoked, so you can answer your own question about concurrency. I personally use DataNucleus with no problem; getObjectById returns what is in the DB at that point for the txn isolation I have set. It throws an exception when the object is not found in the DB (as per the JDO spec).